# timescaledb's retention policy not working

Tags: timescaledb

We have set a retention policy of 72 hours on a table which has column with definition as timestamp without time zone.

When we check after 72 hours, data was not deleted from table.

Update 26 Aug 2021

Added sample data for analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwnDu.png)

Comment: Hello... could you edit the question to share the code you used to set the policy please and also share the table definition? Is it on a hypertable? If it's an integer based timestamp column then you need to use different syntax to a date based timestamp column. 

_disclosure: I work for Timescale_

Comment: SELECT add_retention_policy ('hypertable', INTERVAL '72 hours'); Yes. It's on hypertable.  Column definition = insert_time_stamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2)

Answer (score 2):

The retention policy runs on a schedule in the background jobs. You can also check the background jobs and see the details:

```sql
SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.jobs where application_name like 'Compression%';
```

Then, with the `job_id` it's possible to check the [job_stats](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/informational-views/job_stats/):

```sql
SELECT job_id, total_runs, total_failures, total_successes 
  FROM timescaledb_information.job_stats
  WHERE job_id IN (
    SELECT job_id 
      FROM timescaledb_information.jobs
      WHERE application_name like 'Compression%');
```

Comment: Kindly refer sample data @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwnDu.png